# .htpasswd not working - maybe because of reference

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a server which i'm trying to setup a password on via .htaccess and .htpasswd. Here is my server document structure:

[image]

The only path it shows higher than var is "/" which i'm assuming means root. Both my .htaccess and .htpasswd live in the dashboard folder you can see highlighted in the photo above. Here is the code for each:

.htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/dashboard/.htpasswd
require valid-user
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.html?id=$1 [QSA]
```

.htpasswd:

```
testing123:testing123
```

My best guess is that the path for `AuthUserFile` is wrong and it's not finding my password file but not sure if anyone can spot why it's wrong or if it's something else?

Comment: When you say it is not working - is no form of authentication just showing up? Did you clear your cache? The code looks fine.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/password_encryptions.html

Comment: so the auth box is popping up but it's not accepting the credentials I give it

Comment: I cleared my cache as well so rules that out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I have to encrypt my password in the .htpasswd file. I used this tool here:

https://davidwalsh.name/web-development-tools

Comment: Yes you do ! I was unaware that you hadn't done that. Just figured you where using the above as an example. Always encrypt your passwords.